# Force loading of all Angular modules

Tags: html, angular, typescript, module, routes

### Force loading of all Angular modules

How do I start all the modules of my application on the first run so that I can navigate offline?

My system works with data base in offline mode, as access to the pages the modules load and if it is without connection with you to navigate even without internet.

I would like to load without having to access the pages, loading all the modules on the first startup.

Comment: You may be looking for https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro

Comment: Thank you, I'll check and I'll give you a return.